# How to Use Keytool API instead of Process Builder in Java 8?

Tags: java, security, keytool

Currently we are using Java Process Builder to execute keytool command in my application. Could any one help to how to achive java Keytool API?

**Eg command:**

```
keytool -keystore /tmp/cert/client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file /tmp/cert/ca-cert -storepass password -keypass password -noprompt
```

**Sample Java Process Builder:**

```
    String cmd = "keytool -keystore /tmp/cert/client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file /tmp/cert/ca-cert -storepass password -keypass password -noprompt"
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command(cmd);
    try {
      Process process = processBuilder.start();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      String output = in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
      int exitVal = process.waitFor();
      if (exitVal == 0) return output;
      LOGGER.error(String.format(String.format("Certificate creation Failed %s", output)));
      return null;
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException exception) {
      LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`keytool` is command line tool. If you are updating your keystore programmatically, you should use `KeyStore` api. Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html).

Looks like you are trying to add a certificate. The method you can use to do it programmatically is [setCertificateEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html#setCertificateEntry(java.lang.String,java.security.cert.Certificate)).